# Load matlab .mat export of signal logs in python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mat-file

I am exporting signals in matlab R2023a like this:

```
save logs.mat logsout -v7
```

v7 is recomended version for reading the file in python (seen in different threads).

However, the file read by python is different from what I have in matlab. In matlab I have a nice dataset:

[image: matlab]

but after reading it in python with following code:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat  # this is the SciPy module that loads mat-files
mat = loadmat('logs.mat')
```

this is what I see:

[image: in python]

Instead of structure, I have a array of shape `(1, 277355408)`. What do I miss? I need to process the signals in python after generating.

Comment: What kind of processing do you plan on doing?

Comment: (1) Does `mat` file that you saved contain a bunch of scalars? From your screenshot it looks like they're all scalars, unless I'm missing something. (2) Your screenshot of the variable explorer (I'm guessing that is Spyder) doesn't show the `mat` variable. Have you confirmed it's shape?

Comment: `loadmat` can handle matlab `matrix`, `cell`, and `struct`.  Looks like it can't handle a `dataset`

Comment: @jared yes it is spyder. The dataset contains time vectors. The screenshot shows what it shows when I open mat variable loaded in python.

Comment: @hpaulj you might be correct, I started experimenting with hdf5 format. That seems to be working. I will write answer tomorrow if it is correct. Also I need it as a feed for a neural network, that's why python :)

Comment: `MatlabOpaque` is `loadmat's` way of describing something that it can't parse or convert to Python.  I'm not sure what the `__function_workspae__` is.  `loadmat` was developed years ago, before MATLAB had classes or could save functions.  Hence it's limits.  Plus, it's hard to port functions and such across languages.  All loadmat can create at the python end are `numpy` arrays.  Even with those the result can be a complex nesting of object dtype arrays and structured arrays.

Comment: I've answered an occasional question about loading hdf5 matlab files.  I can open a file with `h5py`, and look at the groups and datasets - which it loads as numpy arrays.  There's also some third party code that facilitates that.  Still I don't know how matlab would save functions/classes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, as suggested by @hpaulj - loadmat can handle matlab matrix, cell, and struct. Looks like it can't handle a dataset. I solved it by exporting variables alone like this:

```
logsout{1}.Values.Data 
save(logsout{1}.Name, 'ans', '-v7')
```

Just an example for first signal.

Now I can read it with scipy. However, there is also way to save it as hdf5 file and read and work with it as follows:

```
import nexusformat.nexus as nx
f = nx.nxload('logs.h5')
prem = f.tree # this can be used to print the tree

#or like this
import h5py
f = h5py.File('logs.h5', 'r')
```